# How to intercept all requests for favicon.ico in SpringMVC?

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, spring-mvc, favicon

I've got a controller that will respond to `/favicon.ico` appropriately.

But I just realized that when you're in a sub page such as `/subpage/index.html` the browser (at least chrome) is requesting `/subpage/favicon.ico`.

Is there a clean way to just respond to all favicon.ico requests? I'd rather not redirect all .ico requests if possible, but if that's the best solution, perhaps.

Comment: How about approaching this from a content type rather than a path. ContentNegotiatingViewResolver?

Comment: I'm leery of intercepting all icons (a future gotcha waiting to happen), which is what I think you suggest. But not a bad idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, one option I just finagled out of my fingers using the controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class PublicPagesController extends BaseController {
    @RequestMapping("**/favicon.ico")
    public String favIconForward(){
        return "forward:/public/img/fav.ico";
    }

    // ...other stuff...
}
```

Note the need to use the file name fav.ico, if you try this using file name favicon.ico you'll get an infinite loop.

I previously was using this approach for just `@RequestMapping("favicon.ico")`

And this assumes you're serving static content out of `/public` with something like this:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/public/**" location="/public/"/>
```